# PHP & HTMl Mix in a PHP $Var

Tags: php, html, syntax

Mixing html and php is simple:

```
<? while($row): ?>
    <p><?=$row['name'] ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But how could i store html like this into a php variable? (Purposed syntax, but doesn't work)

```
<? $html = ?>
    <p>My HTML!!</p>
<? ; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how:

```
$html = <<< HTML
    <p>My HTML!!</p>
HTML;
```

That is know as php [heredoc](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html)

**Note:** You should place closing heredoc keyword without any spaces or indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) when declaring the string:

```
<?php
    $html = <<<HTML
    <p>My HTML!!</p>
HTML;
?>
```

This treats anything between the start `<<<HTML` (`HTML` is the identifier) and the end `HTML` as a string. Note that the closing identifier must be the first in a new line without any indention.

Comment: @Gumbo: you initially used only <<. I am not saying that i have more knowledge than you probably but you must have mis-typed it. thanks :)

Comment: @Gumbo: and moderators do have this stored, i mean edits. thanks